# C external variables in multiple C codes

Tags: c

i created a menu using SDL library, and whenever you click on an item in that menu it should lead you to another C program that do specific task , that's one of the mouse click events:

```
    else if (event.button.x >= 80
          && event.button.x <= 232
          && event.button.y >= 77
          && event.button.y <= 111
          && display == 2)
    {
        system( "  start cmd /k  insertion  ");
    }
```

like inserting a client in the linked list, or show all the elements in the linked lists ...

the problem is, each time the program of insertion gets executed the linked list is empty again, is there any solution to keep the linked lists elements and display them when the display button is clicked.

I tried creating a header with an external struct variable

Comment: I don't believe there's anywhere near enough code here for us to look at; please try to create a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: [Why `system` is evil](http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/j3wTURfi/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [I] created a menu using SDL library , and whenever you click on an
>   item in that menu it should lead you to another C program that do
>   specific task [...]

That's not inherently wrong, but it *is* unusual.

> like inserting a client in the linked list [...]

It's unusual because launching a whole separate program is both costly and poorly suited to tasks such as that.

> the problem is , each time the program of
>   insertion gets executed the linked list is empty again

Yes, of course it is.  In general, separate programs do not share memory, so the program you launch modifies *its own* linked list, not the one belonging to the main program.  Most implementations have facilities available for establishing memory that is shared between programs, but

- even shared memory usually is not suitable for linked lists in particular, and
- I think you probably would be better off gaining more experience before you go there.

> , is there any
>   solution to keep the linked lists elements and display them when the
>   display button is clicked

Yes.  The typical approach would be for the button's callback to call a function in the same program instead of launching a whole separate program.

> i tried creating a header with an external
>   struct variable

External variables are accessible everywhere in the same program.  More specifically, each execution of a given program has its own copies of all the relevant external variables.  They are "external" with respect to the source files in which they are declared and used, not with respect to the program(s) built from those sources.

Comment: thanks , the only program i have with calling a function in the same program , is that i won't get an external cmd prompt that i can right on , any idea how to do so ?

Comment: @enienieni, When you launch a child process via `system()`, it inherits the parent's terminal and standard streams.  Anything you can do with those in the child process, you can also do directly in the parent (and anything you *cannot* do in the parent, you cannot do in the child, either).  However, you are writing a GUI application, so it would be conventional to use GUI idioms -- dialog boxes, input fields, menus, buttons, *etc*. to obtain input from the user.

Comment: i tried using ttf_fonts and designed a GUI for it , but i found some problems during that , also i can't use anything other than C , so i decided to put it in a terminal instead

Answer (score 1):

When you execute an external program, it runs as a separate process. The processes do not share memory space, thus whatever that other program does in its own variables is lost when it's done running. There are several things you can do, and I list just a few in order of increasing complexity:

1. Keep all sub-programs as functions in the main program. Data sharing is then easy. This is by far the easiest option to implement.
2. The sub-program (e.g. `insertion`) can save its data in a disk file. The first program can then read the data. The data has to be formatted for storage in a file, i.e. in most cases you can't write C data structures to disk directly, since e.g. pointer values are only valid within the process that uses them, etc.
3. The initiating program can share a dedicated memory area with the sub-program. This removes the need to deal with disk files, but doesn't "fix" the pointer problems. In general, the shared memory area will be mapped to a different virtual address in each process, and thus the pointers won't be valid. The API used to manage shared memory is platform-specific, and often less-than-intuitive.

I'd highly suggest using option #1, and not dealing with separate sub-programs.

Since what you're doing is clearly a school coursework assignment, it may be that the assignment *requires* that you use separate programs. You have to re-read the assignment carefully and perhaps confirm with the teacher that you do in fact need to use separate program. If it's the case that separate programs are required, there are ways to represent the data in a binary format that is easy to use from within C, but doesn't require transferring pointers around. You could use some text format, but the problem in general doesn't depend on whether the data uses a binary or text representation. What you're storing is a graph: each pointer is an edge in the graph, and each item of data is a graph node. Whether that's written out as text or in binary doesn't matter.

Comment: Thanks for your answer , also i don't really need separate programs , i just didn't find any other way around it i tried rendering text in the screen using sdl too and sometimes it works other time it wont , that's why i wanted an external cmd prompt to complete the job without having to deal with SDL ttf_fonts and the graphical side in general

Comment: Maybe you could use some bitmap font instead, and include it with your program.